# php arrays sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

I have 2 arrays like those:

```
$a = array(152,32,113,47,53);

$b = array("a","w","lk","qw","ol");
```

I will sort $a by using asort() and I want to auto-sort the second array $b likewise $a.

How to do I?

Comment: so, what's the result you want?

Comment: I think he wants the same indexes after the sort on $a to be the same as $b?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Answer (score 3):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php